# How to i get image from gallery in android Q?

Tags: image-gallery, android-10.0

In my code i use MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA for getting image location but in Android Q its getting deprecated could you please suggest some example or solution of this issue. thanks

```
   final String[] columns = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID,
                        MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.ORIENTATION};
                final String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN;
         Cursor imageCursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns, null, null, orderBy + " DESC" );
                while (imageCursor.moveToNext()) {
                    Uri uri = Uri.parse(imageCursor.getString(imageCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA)));

                  /*  Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                            MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                            imageCursor.getLong(Integer.parseInt(BaseColumns._ID)));*/

                    Uri uris = Uri.parse("file://" + uri);
                    if(!new File(uris.getPath()).exists() || uris.toString().contains(".gif") || uris.toString().contains(".GIF"))
                        continue;
                    mediaList.add(new ExternalMediaFileBean(uris,false));

    //            }
 imageCursor.close();
            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse(imageCursor.getString(imageCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA)));
```

with:

```
Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, imageCursor.getLong(imageCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID)));
```

Also, get rid of the code in that loop that is trying to check for things based on file extension.